# Mobile sql java application

Tags: java, sql-server, mobile, jdbc

I've been learning to interface between java and an SQL server with the use of JDBC, and am now about to attempt to extract data (and in the future plan to perhaps upload it as well).

The mobile program will interface with machines on a factory workfloor to produce data about the current job being worked on, and in theory be able to edit these jobs as well. There is a main desktop program being worked on, and this mobile program could be used in tandem with this.

My question is how feasible it is to create a mobile/tablet application in java which can both interface with the machines to extract the data (Currently in the form of .mdf files, which I'm assuming I could utilise sql-server compact) to create graphs showing this data, and if I would just continue to use JDBC to develop this!

(First question, so let me know if additional information is required or if this isn't appropriate for the forum)

Thanks!

Comment: Please don't use JDBC to access server data from mobile applications for security reasons.

Comment: Is security an issue if it's accessing just a basic database with job details? And if so, do you have a suggestion for a better system? Thanks :)

Comment: IMHO it is. If you enable direct JDBC access over the internet, your data isn't safe, DOS attacks are really easy, and you'd better not have any other databases with more confidential data on that server... Build a simple webservice, exchange the data in JSON in XML format. Another advantage is that you can change the database structure without having to change/redeploy the mobile application.